# Update a sprite's height in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to scale a sprite's height exactly to a fixed value. I don't think the function scaleBy() or scaleTo() could help. Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each CCSprite object has properties for the scale, scaleX and scaleY. In your case, you should use the scaleY property and do some simple maths :

```
sprite.scaleY = DESIRED_HEIGHT/sprite.contentSize.height;
```

But you have to make sure that your desired height is in float, otherwise you might get some issues, like always having 0 or 1 as a result!

If you want to animate it, you can also use the CCScaleTo action like this :

```
float scaleY = DESIRED_HEIGHT/sprite.contentSize.height;
[sprite runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration scaleX:sprite.scaleX scaleY:scaleY]];
```

Hope this helps!